# Change font in Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I compiled this code in Word and it pops out:

> Compile error: Expected: expression

This occurs when I change

```
.Font.Name <> "Times New Roman"
```

Here's the code:

```
Public Sub ChangeFonts()
SelectAllInstancesOfStyle ("Normal")
  With Selection.Find
     ' Clear all previously set formatting for Find dialog box.
     .ClearFormatting
     ' Set font to Find for replacement.
     .Font.Name <> "Times New Roman"

     ' Clear all previously set formatting for Replace dialog box.
     .Replacement.ClearFormatting
     ' Set font to Replace found font.
     .Replacement.Font.Name = "Verdana"
     ' Don't find or replace any text.
     .Text = ""
     .Replacement.Text = ""
     ' The following parameters must be set as follows
     ' to find only text formatted for the specified font.
     .Forward = True
     .Wrap = wdFindContinue
     .Format = True
     .MatchCase = False
     .MatchWholeWord = False
     .MatchWildcards = False
     .MatchSoundsLike = False
     .MatchAllWordForms = False
  End With
  ' Perform the find and replace.
  Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

Comment: That doesn't make any sense.  What is it supposed to mean?

Comment: @SLaks i would like to change the fonts which are not Times New Roman to Verdana.

Comment: I don't think `Find` supports that.  `Font.Name` is an ordinary property which can be assigned a single value.

Comment: @SLaks then got any ways to solve this problem?

Comment: You could run through each character in the selection and check its font: if it's not TNR then set it to Verdana.  Might be a bit slow but should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example to change font by paragraphs:

```
Sub sof20319889ChangeFontsByParagraphs()
  Dim i As Long, objParag
  i = 0
  For Each objParag In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
    'Debug.Print i & ": " & objParag.Range.Font.Name
    If (objParag.Range.Font.Name <> "Times New Roman") Then
      objParag.Range.Font.Name = "Verdana"
    End If
    i = i + 1
  Next
End Sub
```